# How do I filter the results of an aggregation in IBM Watson discovery service

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

In Watson discovery service I am already aggregating my documents to get the top concepts. Using the following query:

```
term(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text,count:10)
```

However, my source material is already concentrated around a few central concepts. In this case Ice Hockey, so what I want to do is be able to then filter out thosse concepts. with a query that looks something like this:

```
term(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text,count:10).filter(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text:!("National Hockey League"|"Ice hockey"))
```

This however does not work. I can get it to work if I filter first:

```
filter(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text:!("National Hockey League"|"Ice hockey")).term(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text,count:10)
```

The Issue with this however is it filters the documents with the concept "Ice Hockey" and then aggregates the results. I want to get the list of concepts and then filter THAT down, without lossing any documents.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to accomplish your task with the `nested` aggregation to achieve your goal.

`nested` will scope the aggregation to the subdocuments (which is what the concepts are)

So my suggestion would be to run the following query:

```
nested(enriched_metadata_text.concepts).filter(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text:!("National Hockey League"|"Ice hockey")).term(enriched_metadata_text.concepts.text,count:10)
```

Please let me know if this works!

Comment: Hi Andrew.

That exact query did not work, it using the discovery tooling it just leaves the spinner going round and round. I will read the discovery docs now to understand more what 'nested' does.